# While Loop breaking when condition not met

Tags: c#, while-loop

Please refer to the code snippet below

```
while (bContinue == true)
{
    if (userSelect == "Create a ticket")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to full all fields? [Y/N]\n");
        char chInfo = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        if (chInfo == 'y' || chInfo == 'Y')
        {
            /* I have removed the console.readline functions that assign the object in order to make it easier for people to read and assist with my problem.*/

            objTick = new Ticket(strTicketCreator, strTicketStaffID, strTicketEmail, strTicketDesc);
            bContinue = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            objTick = new Ticket(strTicketStaffID, strTicketDesc);
        }

        activeTickets.Add(objTick);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to make another ticket? [Y/N]\n");
    char chNewTicket = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

    if (chNewTicket == 'n' || chNewTicket == 'N')
        bContinue = false;
}
```

The problem I am experiencing is that if the user would like to make another ticket, they are unable to as the while loop breaks if they input 'y' which is assigned to chNewTicket. This is the unexpected case.

However this only happens if the user inputs 'y' to the question "Would you like to full all fields".

I am thinking potentially that the if statement inside the while loop may have something to do with it but I am quite unsure as I am quite new to coding in c# or coding in general.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: you set `bContinue` to `false` in an earlier block... you don't then reset it to `true` if the user replies "y" to creating another ticket. You could just change the last part to `bContinue = !(chNewTicket == 'n' || chNewTicket == 'N');` so that it would assign a new value either way.

Comment: Once you've set `bContinue = false;` the loop will end unless you set it back to true before it is checked again.

Comment: As a side note, the use of `b` and `ch` prefixes (similar to what's often called a Hungarian naming convention, potentially inaccurately) is not idiomatic in C#.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I feel like an idiot, i've gone over the code so many times and never saw that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JonSkeet Just curious what is a more suitable naming convention to use in c#? Just to further my practice with programming in c#.

Comment: Just remove the prefixes, and choose different names where they'd collide with keywords. So I'd use `ticketStaffId` and `ticketDescription` for example... I'd give suggestions for the other parts, but I'd probably refactor those anyway, and potentially use a `do/while` loop instead of a `while` loop, with a method returning `bool` to ask the user a yes/no question (to avoid code duplication).

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay yup I will definitely implement those suggestions just to achieve a better grade on my assessment. Thanks Jon!